# Why does a request to unsubscribe from a mailing list take a long time?

Tags: email

Whenever I unsubscribe from a mailing list, I see that they say something like 'The change will take effect in 10 days/30 days/etc'. I would assume unsubscribing is just removing my email from some database. What is the idea behind making me wait so many days?

PS: This [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/97948/33016) was closed from "Programmers.stackoverflow" as offtopic and I was suggested to open here.

Comment: This is also offtopic here (being entirely web-based) and I don't really know where it would be on-topic.  I don't think it would fit on Server Fault or Webapps...hmm.

Comment: It's not suitable (in it's current form) for anywhere really.

Answer (score 1):

Actually unsubscriptions are made by mailing lists`s moderators. It is only a human factor, not technical or inhernt to an application in specific.